# Symlink - require_once doesn't seem to work?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, symlink, require-once

I store my WordPress theme in my Dropbox to use it easily on many machines. Unfortunately require_once()/include_once() doesn't seem to work for me.

Is store original theme at `G:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wordpress\Themes\Blabla\`

The symlink is placed at `C:\xampp\htdocs\blabla\wp-content\themes\Blabla`

When I wanted to require/include any file, eg. `C:\xampp\htdocs\blabla\wp-load.php` I used to do `require_once('../../wp-load.php');`

But with symlink all I got is:

> **Warning**:  require_once(../../../wp-load.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   **G:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wordpress\Themes\Blabla\foo\bar.php** on line
>   **2**
>  
>  **Fatal error**:  require_once(): Failed
>   opening required '../../../wp-load.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   **G:\Dropbox\Dropbox\Wordpress\Themes\Blabla\foo\bar.php** on line
>   **2**

Looks like require_once looks for the file within the Dropbox, not symlink context? Is it possible to fix it somehow? I can't use absolute path as I develop on different machines / different OSes and those vary... Any ideas? How does require_once work when it's symlinked? Does it look for required file in both places (original-context & symlink-context)?

Comment: use complete path like from root `\xampp\htdocs\blabla\wp-load.php`

Comment: can you modify the include path with `set_include_path()`?

Comment: user790454, it's pointless as it will only work on this one machine.  Viktor Svensson, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about putting the original file into you Wordpress folder and symlinking to dropbox?
While installing this, you should turn off dropbox on all machines where you did not move the folder yet.